# upload sketch via bluetooth for android

Tags: arduino-uno, uploading, android

How can i convert file .ino to hex file so that i can compile new sketch via bluetooth. Can you help me to figure out the way to do this? thanks for helping

Comment: You press the "verify" button in the IDE. That makes a .hex file. But I don't think that's really your question, though, is it? Getting a HEX file is the easy part. Uploading from android isn't. You would need something to implement the Arduino bootloader protocol in Android. No clue if there is anything out there to do that for you or not. Maybe Google can help?

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.iotool.iotoolarduinohex&hl=en_GB

Comment: i mean like bluino app or arduinodroid app they can compile code via bluetooth, so i really wants to understand  how arduino receives data. Sorry sir because my question isn't clear. hope you help

Comment: You don't compile code via bluetooth. You compile code on your computer, then copy the compiled .hex file to your phone to upload with whatever app you choose.

Comment: so i need to find way compile it by java or computer, and then send compiled .hex file to arduino via bluetooth to make it work

Comment: `You press the "verify" button in the IDE.`  -- Then you use your favourite file transfer tool over whatever protocol you prefer (I use Amaze to access a share through the network). Then you use the Arduino programmer app.

Comment: let me explain what i aim to do , that i want to make an android app that can create ino  then upload it via bluetooth to arduino to make robot work and instead of controlling just send a string to control that i would want replace a whole file in arduino chip

Comment: So you want to write your own Android-based IDE, and port the compiler to Android? Good luck with that. There's a reason people write web-based applications...

Comment: thank you sir, you are so nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very hard to understand exactly what you want to do, but from what I can gather you want to:

1. Write an Android application that lets you edit sketches
2. Compile those sketches on an android device, and
3. Upload those compiled sketches to an Arduino over Bluetooth

While what you are asking is *technically* possible, it is not *realistically* practical.

Writing a text editor in Android is easy enough. That's not a problem. It's the compilation of the code that is not practical.

You would need to port the compiler (a very large project written in C) to Android. That would essentially need to remain as compiled C code, and so you would have to individually port it to each possible platform you want it to run on (various different types of ARM, Intel, etc) and for different versions of android.

Unless you're a genius at Android and C programming that's just not going to happen.

A more practical way would be to write a web-based application that allows you to edit your sketches, which can then run the compiler on a real computer (no porting needed then), which can then download the compiled HEX file to your Android device, then use a pre-existing application to program that HEX file over bluetooth.

Alternatively, just use the Arduino Create website to compile and download your HEX file.